# How to show an array of Texts sequentially with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of strings I want to show to the user, sequentially. For example:

```
var array = ["Hey there!", "What's your name?"]
```

What I specifically want, is to show the first string for a few seconds and when that time passes, show the next.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var array = ["Hey there!", "What's your name?"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TimedTextView(text: array.first, numberOfVisibilitySeconds: 3, onFinishedShowing: {
                self.array.removeFirst()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And here’s `TimedTextView`:

```
struct TimedTextView: View {
    @State private var shouldMakeTextVisible = true

    var text: String!
    var numberOfVisibilitySeconds: Double!
    var onFinishedShowing: (() -> Void)!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if shouldMakeTextVisible {
                Text(text)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                    .animation(.easeIn)
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + numberOfVisibilitySeconds) {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.shouldMakeTextVisible.toggle()
                            }
                        
                            self.onFinishedShowing()
                        }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a closure to inform `ContentView` that the `Text` is done showing and to get the next one. But, what actually happens is that I see only the first string... Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
struct TimedTextContainer: View {
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var isVisible = true

    let textArray: [String]

    var visibilityFor: TimeInterval
    var delay: TimeInterval

    var body: some View {
        if currentIndex < textArray.count, isVisible {
            Text(textArray[currentIndex])
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .id(currentIndex)
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                .animation(.easeIn)
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + visibilityFor) {
                        withAnimation {
                            isVisible = false
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + visibilityFor + delay) {
                        withAnimation {
                            currentIndex += 1
                            isVisible = true
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let textArray = ["Hey there!", "What's your name?"]

    var body: some View {
        TimedTextContainer(textArray: textArray, visibilityFor: 3, delay: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks!